# Kendo UI hidecolumn/showcolumn performance with many columns

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to hide and show columns in my grid using Kendo UI hidecolumn and showcolumn methods, it works however it looks like the grid lags in showing and hiding column when there are many columns in grid. I have about  50 columns in my grid. Also after hiding the columns, the column doesn't realign in the grid even after using refresh method of the grid.
 Does anyone know what's an alternative way to hide/show column without loosing the performance in the grid?

Thanks.
Sanjeev

Comment: I've done this functionality on server side. And every change (hide/show) saved into database. So when user comes to the page only "active" columns are shown and I have not any problem with performance. The only thing what I had to change is "column menu", i didn't show default one but created button (in toolbar) which openes dialog window with column options ... Maybe this approach can be helpfull for you also. If you will be interested I can post some short example, but note that I am not owner of kendo grid mvc, so I can show only kendo grid javascript syntax..

Comment: @Ademar, can you post your short example for this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, you just need to know, that [columns](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns) in grid is nothing more than usual array. So you can create this array separately and assign into grid configuration.

I done it for configuration of whole grid but I try show only columns part, because example will be relative long because I will try show all important methods. Anyway I hope it helps you.

So process can be (but don't have to) be something like this:

1. Prepare database table. If you need save only visible/hid value, you can be satisfied with basic table like this:

   > ```
   > CREATE TABLE dbo.TableSettings( 
   >     Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
   >     [Key] VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL, 
   >     Name VARCHAR(MAX) NULL, 
   >     Value BIT NULL );
   > ```

   In my case table has more columns but for save this information this is enough. [Key] is table name in my case (dbo.[User] for example), Name is name of column (FirstName for example) and Value is Visible/hid (1/0).
2. Now you need to load columns settings from database and save it into array witch will be assigned into grid config.

   ```
   RunSynchronousAjax(address, null, function (e) {

       var options = JSON.parse(e.Config);
       var columns = options.Columns;

       //This part is needed only if you have some special cases which are prepared on server. It is because on server you cannot assign function like in javascript but you have to assign only name of function which need to be eval in javascript.
       for (var i = 0; i < options.columns.length; i++) {
           options.columns[i].filterable.ui = eval(options.columns[i].filterable.ui);
           if (options.columns[i].filterable.itemTemplate != undefined) {
               options.columns[i].filterable.itemTemplate = eval(options.columns[i].filterable.itemTemplate);
           }
       }
   }, defaultErrorCallBack);
   ```

   Note: RunSynchronousAjax is my helper method for processign ajax request because I didn't want write it everztime I need it. It looks like this:

   ```
   function RunSynchronousAjax(url, data, successCallback, errorCallback) {
       jQuery.ajax({
           contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
           url: url,
           data: data,
           type: "POST",
           cache: false,
           success: function (json) {
               successCallback(json);
           },
           error: function (data) {
               errorCallback(data);
           },
           async: false
       });
   }

   function defaultErrorCallback(data) {
       alert("Unexpected error. Please, try press CTRL+F5.");
   }
   ```
3. This function is way how I load config for table, now let's look on method in controller.

   ```
   public JsonResult GetSetting()
   {

       KendoGrid grid = new KendoGrid();

       grid.PrepareColumns();

       string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(grid);
       return Json(new
       {
           Config = json
       });
   }
   ```
4. Objects looks like this

   ```
   public class KendoGrid
   {

       ...
       private List<Column> _Columns = new List<Column>();
       [JsonProperty("columns")]
       public List<Column> Columns
       {
           get { return this._Columns; }
           set { this._Columns = value; }
       }
       ...
   }

   public class Column
   {


       [JsonProperty("field")]
       public string Field { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty("title")]
       public string Title { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty("type")]
       public string Type { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty("width")]
       public string Width { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty("filterable")]
       public object Filterable { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty("template")]
       public string Template { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty("order")]
       public int Order { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty("format")]
       public string Format { get; set; }

      .... and more ... just what you need

       public Column(
           string field,
           string title = null,
           string type = "string",
           string width = null,
           string template = null,
           object filterable = null,
           string format = null,
           ...)
       {
           this.Field = field;
           this.Title = title ?? field;
           this.Type = type;
           this.Width = width;
           this.Template = template;
           this.Order = order;
           this.Format = format;
           ....
       }
   ```
5. In point 3 there is method PrepareColumns, it looks like this

   ```
   public void PrepareColumns()
       {

           var listOfColumns = TableSettings.GetColumns("dbo.TableName");

           this.Columns.AddNotNull(Column.GetColumn<ObjectWhichIsDisplayedInGrid>(x => x.Id, listOfColumns,
           type: "number",
           width: "140px", 
           ...));

           this.Columns.AddNotNull(Column.GetColumn<ObjectWhichIsDisplayedInGrid>(x => x.Name, listOfColumns,
               width: "250px",
               ...));
   .....
   }

   //This method is based on you, It just load records from db...


   public static List<TableSettings> GetColumns(string key)
       {


           List<TableSettings> result = new List<TableSettings>();

           var query = Sql.Builder
               .Select("*")
               .From("dbo.TableSettings")
               .Where("[Key] = @0", key)
               .OrderBy("OrderInTable");

           using (IDatabase db = DbConnection.Connect())
           {
               result = db.Fetch<TableSettings>(query);
           }

           return result;
       }


   public static Column GetColumn<T>(
       Expression<Func<T, object>> expression,
       List<TableSettings> settings,
       string type = "string",
       string width = null,
       string template = null,
       ...)
       {


           var fieldName = PropertyNameHelper.PropertyName<T>(expression);
           var fieldDescription = PropertyNameHelper.PropertyDescription<T>(expression);

           var column = settings.Where(c => c.Name.Replace(" ", string.Empty).ToLower() == fieldName.Replace(" ", string.Empty).ToLower()).FirstOrDefault();

           Column col = new Column(
           field: fieldName,
           title: fieldDescription,
           type: type,
           ....);

           return col;
       }

   public static string PropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
       {
           return GetPropertyName(expression);
       }

   public static string PropertyDescription<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
       {


           var propertyName = GetPropertyName(expression);
           PropertyInfo prop = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);

           if (prop.IsDefined(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false))
           {
               return (prop.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false) as DisplayAttribute).Name;
           }

           return propertyName;
       }
   ```
6. That's it. First 5 points is about load columns configuration from database. What is saved as not visible, will not be loaded so kendo grid will know only about columns which are visible.

Now, I have talked about my own columnMenu. It is only usual popup window with options. Important is that grid has set [columnMenu](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columnMenu) to false, so default functionality is off. I have added button into toolbar and click event has opened kendoWindow where I had checkboxes with columns names. I can check what I want to display and after popup is closed/confirmed, some ajax request is called - it is saved into database and grid is refreshed.

Anyway mainly it can gives you idea, I believe there is much more solutions for this. If you find way how to create columns array dynamically you will win.